# Running local-exec provisioner on all EC2 instances after creation

Tags: terraform

I currently have a Terraform file to create EC2 instances on AWS that looks like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "influxdata" {
  count      = "${var.ec2-count-influx-data}"

  ami           = "${module.amis.rhel73_id}"
  instance_type = "${var.ec2-type-influx-data}"

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.sg-ids}"]
  subnet_id              = "${element(module.infra.subnet,count.index)}"
  key_name               = "${var.KeyName}"
  iam_instance_profile   = "Custom-role"

  tags {
    Name               = "influx-data-node"
    ASV                = "${module.infra.ASV}"
    CMDBEnvironment    = "${module.infra.CMDBEnvironment}"
    OwnerContact       = "${module.infra.OwnerContact}"
    custodian_downtime = "off"
    OwnerEid           = "${var.OwnerEid}"
  }


  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sdg"
    volume_size = 500
    volume_type = "io1"
    iops = 2000
    encrypted = true
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  user_data = "${file("terraform/attach_ebs.sh")}"

  connection {
    private_key = "${file("/Users/usr111/Downloads/usr111_CD.pem")}"
    user        = "ec2-user"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["echo just checking for ssh. ttyl. bye."]
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
ansible-playbook base-data.yml --key-file=/Users/usr111/Downloads/usr111_CD.pem --user=ec2-user -b -i "${self.private_ip},"
    EOF
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "influx-data-route" {

  count = "${var.ec2-count-influx-data}"
  zone_id = "${var.r53-zone}"
  name = "influx-data-0${count.index}"
  type = "A"
  ttl = "300"
  // matches up record N to instance N
  records = ["${element(aws_instance.influxdata.*.private_ip, count.index)}"]
}

resource "local_file" "inventory-meta" {
  filename = "inventory"

  content = <<-EOF
[meta]
${join("\n",aws_instance.influxmeta.*.private_ip)}

[data]
${join("\n",aws_instance.influxdata.*.private_ip)}
  EOF
}
```

What I'm struggling to figure out is to get this part to run *after* I create the inventory file:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
ansible-playbook base-data.yml --key-file=/Users/usr111/Downloads/usr111_CD.pem --user=ec2-user -b -i "${self.private_ip},"
    EOF
  }
```

Right now I'm passing an IP into Ansible but I want to pass in the inventory file, which is only created after Terraform provisions all of the instances.

Comment: Try using depends_on some how? https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using AWS maybe you could try using the [Dynamic Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) script and your provisioner could look like this:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "ansible-playbook -i ec2.py playbook.yml --limit ${self.public_ip}" }
```

In your playbook you are going to need to wait for SSH to become available since Ansible is making the connection and not Terraform.

```
- name: wait for ssh
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - local_action: wait_for port=22 host="{{ ip }}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=10
```

So the command should look like this:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "ansible-playbook -i ec2.py playbook.yml --limit ${self.public_ip}" --extra-vars 'ip=${self.public_ip}'}
```

You can also copy your playbooks to the host with the "File Provisioner", install ansible and run the playbook locally with "remote-exec", but that's up to you.